# rails for zombies lab3 excercise 3, stuck?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The question asks:

> Use an each block to print the names of all the Zombies.

I tried the following code, and it says that the content isn't being rendered.

```
<% zombies = Zombie.all %>

<ul>
<% zombies.each do |zombie|  %>
<li>
<=% zombies.name %>
<% end%>
</li>

</ul>
```

Is something wrong with this Rails code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML-Structure is messed up:

```
<% zombies.each do |zombie|  %>
<li>
<=% zombies.name %>
<% end%>
</li>
```

should be

```
<% zombies.each do |zombie|  %>
  <li>
    <%= zombie.name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a proper ERB tag on line 6:

```
<%= zombies.name %>
```

Also, at this point, you are trying to call `name` on `zombies`, which is an array (you set it on line 1). If you want to print out the name of the specific zombie that you are currently on, you would use `zombie.name` (no s).

Lastly, you need to move your closing `</li>` tag to before the `<% end %>`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<=% zombies.name %>
```

to

```
<%= zombie.name %>
```